# Overflow:hidden causing jagged fonts in Galaxy S4 Android Browser

Tags: android, css, fonts

On a website I'm building, every browser and device (among many tested) look perfectly fine, but on the Samsung Galaxy S4 in the included Android browser, fonts are extremely jagged... not blurry, but jagged. I've followed every guide I can find on fonts and css related to this, and it looks perfectly fine everywhere except in this one use case. It even looks fine in Chrome on the same device, so fiddling with phone settings didn't seem right, but I did anyway and no change.

I can't post a fiddle of the site because it is a corporate site, and I can't be sharing it as such... but basically, I'm hoping at least for some insights or inspiration here... maybe someone else has run into a similar problem before?

I have narrowed the issue down, by literally systematically deleting CSS rules one by one, until I discovered that the issue seems to be the use of overflow:hidden. Once I remove overflow:hidden from all parents of a text, the jaggedness goes away... but I CANNOT remove that overflow:hidden, as that would break everything else. The font family doesn't seem to matter, it does it no matter what it is.

If anyone has any ideas of how to proceed without removing overflow:hidden, please respond.

Update: It appears to have to do with both position:relative AND overflow:hidden. If both of these are affecting the parent of text, the S4 Android Browser renders it as jagged...